# PyQt5.QtSerialPort don't call connected function when called from other class

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have strange (for me) problem about calling PyQt5.QtSerialPort from other class:

This is serial code class implementation I'd like to call from other dialog or class:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QIODevice, pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtSerialPort import QSerialPort

class Com_port(QObject):
    ser = None
    packet_received = pyqtSignal(int)
    packet = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        super(Com_port, self).__init__()
        #self.buffer = kwds.pop('buffer')
        self.ser = QSerialPort(kwds.pop('port'))
        #self.ser = QSerialPort("COM5")
        self.ser.open(QIODevice.ReadWrite)
        self.ser.setBaudRate(kwds.pop('baudrate'))
        #self.ser.setBaudRate(115200)
        self.ser.readyRead.connect(self.on_serial_read)
        self.packet_received.connect(self.rcvData_signal)

        self.b1_bmsovi=b'\x0d\x0e\x0f\x10\x11\x12'
        self.brojac=0
        self.bms_number=0
        self.b1_bmsovi=b'\x0d\x0e\x0f\x10\x11\x12'
        self.brojac=0
        self.bms_number=0
        print ("Ipak sam prozvan")

    def rcvData_signal(self,bms):
        print(bms)

    def check_packet(self):
        rezultat = 0
        if self.packet[0]==170 and self.packet[1]==200 and self.packet[3]==1 and self.packet[12]==85 and (self.packet[2] in self.b1_bmsovi):
            self.bms_number = self.packet[2]
            rezultat = 1
        return rezultat

    def process_bytes(self, bs):
        """
        """
        for b in bs:
            if b == 170:
                self.brojac=0
            if self.brojac < 13:
                print (b)
                self.packet[self.brojac] = b
                self.brojac += 1
            if self.brojac==12 and self.check_packet()==1:
                self.packet_received.emit(self.bms_number)

    def on_serial_read(self):
        """
            Called when the application gets data from the connected device.
        """
        self.process_bytes(bytes(self.ser.readAll()))
# end of class Com_port

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ComPortApp = Com_port(port="COM5",baudrate=115200)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
    """
    Korisni linkovi
    https://programtalk.com/vs2/python/8876/mu/mu/interface.py/
    """
```

When I execute this code alone I got result from rcvData_signal(self,bms) function which print bms number.

So I'd like to use this class as general serial data source from com port.
I wrote this code just to test Com_port class:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from bms_single_ui import Ui_bms_single
from com_port_thread import Com_port

class bms_single(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        ser=Com_port(port="COM5",baudrate=115200) # Com_port instance
        ComPortApp.packet_received.connect(self.rcvData_signal) #event redir

        self.ui = Ui_bms_single()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("BMS SINGLE PREVIEW")
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        #self.setWindowFlags(Qt.Window | Qt.WindowTitleHint | Qt.CustomizeWindowHint )
        self.setFixedSize(800,480)
        self.move(0, 0)

    def rcvData_signal(self,bms):   # No calling to this :(
        print(bms)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    #ComPortApp = Com_port(port="COM5",baudrate=115200)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

In this case I cant' get any data from Com_port instance :(

But when I uncoment this line #ComPortApp = Com_port(port="COM5",baudrate=115200) at the bottom of the code (and comment all lines about com port in class bms_singe), I got all data from Com_port instance.

What is wrong with calling Com_port class from bms_single class ?

Comment: ComPortApp.packet_received.connect(self.rcvData_signal) #event redir
is not correct at first listing 
it should be 
ser.packet_received.connect(self.rcvData_signal) #event redir

but it is still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html):

> `'__main__'` is the name of the scope in which top-level code executes.
>   A module’s `__name__` is set equal to `'__main__'` when read from standard input, a script, or from an interactive prompt.
>
> [..]

From the above we conclude that only an `if __name__ ==" __main__ "`
is executed:". If this same expression exists in other files, they will be omitted. So you should not use the variable `ComPortApp` since it does not exist, the correct thing is to use the variable `ser`, in your case it changes:

```
ComPortApp.packet_received.connect(self.rcvData_signal)
```

to:

```
ser.packet_received.connect(self.rcvData_signal)
```

The other problem is that the object `ser` is being eliminated by the garbage collector, there are 2 options:

1. Making the variable `ser` class member for it changes to being in `self.ser` in the `bms_single` class.

---

```
self.ser=Com_port(port="COM5",baudrate=115200) # Com_port instance
self.ser.packet_received.connect(self.rcvData_signal) #event redir
```

2. Passing the parent attribute to the Com_port class, you have to change the following:

---

```
ser= Com_port(port="COM5",baudrate=115200, parent=self)
```

and

```
class Com_port(QObject):
    [...]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        super(Com_port, self).__init__(kwds.pop('parent'))
```

I also recommend changing `QWidget.__init__(self, parent)` to `QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)`

Lastly do not forget to create and display an instance of `bms_single` in the main.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = bms_single()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```